# Ubuntu 22.10 does not turn on the second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, 22.10

Lately on ubuntu I can't properly use my second monitor connected using a DisplayPort to VGA adapter with the video card:

```
$ lspci | grep VGA
01: 00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD / ATI] Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X]
```

For the time being I solved by disabling Wayland with:

```
sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

and replacing:

```
# WaylandEnable = false
```

with:

```
WaylandEnable = false
```

Then, when booting the system with xrandr, I reset the screens with:

```
sh -c "xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --off; xrandr --output DisplayPort-1 --auto --right-of DVI-0"
```

What is the cause of this?

Why does ubuntu see the second screen correctly, but does not turn it on forcing me to reset it at every boot?

What can I do to find out what is not working properly?

Comment: I regularly (but not always) I have the same problem too, when logging back in after the computer went to sleep. Your `xrandr` solution then brings back the second screen (or, well, replugging the DP-connector, but I hate doing that even more than running `xrandr`. I was wondering, one month later, if you found any more-permanent solution?

Comment: For now I'm still running `xrandr` automatically on system startup and I've also paired it as a keyboard shortcut to reset the screens in case they stop working.